# How to make function to combine parameters using indeterminate number of parameters and va_list?

Tags: c, parameters, variadic-functions

I want to make a function with this prototype:

```c
char *combine(const char *string, ...)
```

that combines parameters given from the command line and returns the result to `main`.

My function currently looks like this:

```
char *combine(const char *mj, ...)
{
     va_list pl;
     va_start(pl, mj);

     while(mj != NULL) {
        printf("%s",mj);
        mj = va_arg(pl, char *);
     }

     va_end(pl);
     return pl;
}
```

For example, if the user runs this program with the command:

```
./a.out one two three four five six seven
```

The output should be:

```
Parameter: onetwothreefourfivesixseven (length of parameter: 27)
```

Now if I run my program with that, the output is mostly random elements and the parameter is just empty.

What's wrong and what I need to fix so it shows the right thing?

The program needs to work with following `main` code:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  char *mj = malloc(1);

  mj[0] = '\0';
  for(i = 1; (i+3) <= argc; i += 3)
  { 
    char *tmp = mj;
    mj = combine(tmp, argv[i], argv[i+1], argv[i+2], NULL);
    free(tmp);
  }
  if((i+2) == argc)
  {
    char *tmp = mj;
    mj = combine(mj, argv[i], argv[i+1], NULL);
    free(tmp);
  }
  else if((i+1) == argc)
  {
    char *tmp = mj;
    mj = combine(mj, argv[i], NULL);
    free(tmp);
  }
  printf("Parameter: %s (length: %lu)\n", mj, (unsigned long)strlen(mj));
  free(mj);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, there is no attempt to combine the strings you're given, you're just trying to print them.  Then for some reason you try to return your local variable for the `va_list` instead of a `char *`. (Surely your compiler tried to stop you on that one.)

Comment: I'm not quite familiar of using va-list and for some reason I thought that using it combines all my parameters together. Any tips for how to combine those command line arguments together and return them as char*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the `va_list` as an opaque type, as in "never mind what it really is".  The "functions" `va_start()`, `va_arg()`, and `va_end()` are actually not functions, but macros.  Again, what they really are and how they actually work is not that important at first.  ("Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain!")  All you need to know right now is *how to use* them.

Suppose you have your own function that you are writing:

```c
char *combine(const char *mj, ...)
```

There is one argument `const char *mj`, and then... possibly some others.  So how do you refer to these arguments if they have no identifiers, and if you don't even know how many there are?  This is what the `va_list` is used for. Think of it as like a cursor that can scroll through this argument list and can somehow tell you what the next argument is.

First, you have to set it up with `va_start`:

```
va_start(pl, mj);
```

This means to set up the `va_list pl` using `mj` as the *last known explicit argument*.

The first time you use `va_arg()` with `pl`, it will give you the first argument *after* `mj`.  You also need to specify in `va_arg()` the expected type of what you expect this next argument to be, so in your case the call would be `va_arg(pl, char *)`. Every time you use `va_arg()`, it advances this "cursor" such that the next call to `va_arg()` would give you the next argument.  So every time you use `va_arg()` you should do something with this value, because you're not going to get it again.  (Unless, perhaps you start over.)

So how do you know if you're at the end of the list? Well, you just have to know somehow. `va_arg()` will not tell you you're at the end of the list, it will gladly keep going past the end if you keep using it. Typically you would use the last known argument (in your case `mj`) to somehow specify how many arguments there are, or you could look for some sentinel value in your list of arguments.

When you have decided that you are finished, be sure to use

```
va_end(pl);
```

After this point, the `va_list pl` is invalid and shouldn't be referred to again. (Unless you want to start over with another `va_start()`.)

---

One example to illustrate how this might be used is the classic `printf()`, which uses variable arguments. From the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), we know `printf()` is declared as

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

Consider, for example the function call

```
printf("The value of %s is %ld\n", lbl, x);
```

Internally, `printf()` would use some `va_list`, let's call it `vl`. The `format` is the last known argument, so it would be used in `va_start(vl, format)`.  `printf()` would parse this `format` string, find the `%s` and expect to have a `char *` argument next.  It would then call `va_arg(vl, char *)`, use this value somehow, and keep parsing the `format` string.  It then finds `%ld` and expects some `long int`, so it calls `va_arg(vl, long int)` and uses this value when printing.  After parsing `format` more, it comes to the end of the format string, and it stops, eventually using `va_end(vl)`.  (If you're paying attention, perhaps now you can figure out why it is important to always use the proper length modifier and conversion specifier in your `printf` format strings.)

---

So that's *how to use* a `va_list`.  Now back to your code:  Remember that `va_start(pl, mj);` does *not* assign anything to `mj`, as it appears you might think.  It only sets up the `va_list pl` using `mj` as the last known explicit argument.  You are also reassigning `mj` for some reason (that part doesn't make sense).  You are not even trying to concatenate any strings at all.  It looks like you are just trying to print them.  Start with a dynamically allocated buffer of some size, append strings to it one by one, and reallocate as needed.  (This is not hard, but it will seem non-trivial the first time you do it.  How to implement it is beyond the scope of this question.)

`va_list` doesn't "combine" anything, it only gives you the arguments to your function one at a time (it's more like it breaks things apart).  You have to do the combining yourself, `va_list` is just how to get at the pieces.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really good explanation and I finally got it working making new empty array and adding all strings to it using simple sprintf() command. :)

Comment: Watch out for the allocation size. `sprintf()` does **not** check to see if it's writing past the end of the allocation.  (It can't because it has no way of knowing where the end of the allocation is.) Look at [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to do it safely, but you have to keep track of the allocation size and how much has been written by yourself. C is about having full control, but with more power comes more responsibility.